# How to use SQLite in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, sqlite.swift

I'm unable to use the **SQLite** framework in my project. As I'm getting the errors shown in the image. Can anyone help me out to resolve this error.

[image]

**Note:** The project is in **Swift 3.0 and I have used Cocoapod to install the SQLite library**

Comment: What is **CSQLite**? It should be **SQLite**.

Comment: **SQLite** is using **CSQLite** to build and access the sqlite3 library from the os library paths.

Comment: Can you give me the link which SQLite framework for swift you are using?

Comment: @Poles This is the https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift link.

Comment: try this library- https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift , It's easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue,

As **CSQLite module** is trying to access the sqlite3 library from the default path **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h**

But, where as in my case I have installed two xcode apps with different versions named. So I have changed the **Xcode.app** to **Xcode 8.2.1.app**

like 
   **/Applications/Xcode 8.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h**